# How can I record Linux commands?

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, installation, history

Is there a way to record the Linux commands I use and reuse them on another machine or in case I want to reinstall the machine?

In example record how I set up NginX, PHP and permissions in my lab environment and then repeat the exact commands on my deploy machine?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Seems to me like you want [script(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/script).

It allows you to record and replay terminal sessions.

On the other hand, if you are trying to automate setups, consider configuration management, like [puppet](http://reductivelabs.com/products/puppet/).

Comment: Thanks for Puppet, it looks good. I will read more about it.

Comment: +1 for Puppet. This is a much better way to go than simply recording shell commands.

Comment: +1.  cfengine is a competitor to Puppet, also

Answer (score 2):

Two ways I can think of off the top of my head:

- Use the builtin command *[history](http://www.talug.org/events/20030709/cmdline_history.html)*
- Do everything in a screen session and enable [logging](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Log.html#Log)

Answer (score 2):

Bash records commands in a file called ~/.bash_history. This works if you do everything via a command line, and in one command window.

Be warned though, it limits the size of that file to the most recent 1000(by default) commands.

Answer (score 0):

try this out

```
# script /tmp/it356658-$(uname -n).out
# date
```

Comment: He is directing `script`'s output to a particular file. The naming is unusual, but likely extracted from a larger shell script perhaps.

Comment: The `$(uname -n)` is interpreted by the command line to run the `uname` command with the `-n` flag to print out the system's hostname.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could also use **autoexpect** for this task.

Comment: I got "command not found" in Ubuntu when I tried it.

Comment: I think it would be part of the Expect package which may not installed by default. Ref: http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3065

Answer (score 0):

Normally I use a command like `history > ~/tmp/hh` to save a history file.  Then I use `vi`, jump to the bottom with the *G* command and then search upwards until I find the part that would be near a useful entry point into a script.  From there I collapse out extraneous `ls` commands, combine series of incremental `cd` into directories, add comments, and start figuring out which parts need to be arguments, which things might have to be environment settings and which things have to be hard-coded.  I add lots of comments.  Sometimes I "punt" on parts of automating it and just give the user some instructions (go find this setting, `ssh` to foo and ..., uncomment blah from this file and move it to blarg) or `echo` a URL ... and a prompt string like: 'Configured Foo and exit >'

(When you punt on an automated file edit ... I suggest appending the instructive code to the file, as a comment, and use something like the `vi` **+** command line switch to put the editor's cursor near the bottom of the file, at the top of your instructions.  For example with 5 lines of instructive text (a *here doc* for example) you'd add `'+$-5'` to the `vi` command line, before the filename.  (`$-5` is an old `ex` incantation to address the last line of the file, minus five lines; the relatively obscure `+` switch to `vi` accepts any `ex` ... **:** command ... as an argument).

Another trick ... assuming you do most of your work from a X Windowing System terminal (`xterm`, `konsole`, `gnome-terminal`, etc) then keep a browser open on some wiki pages as you go.  Cut and past commands, output, snippets of text files and jot down notes as you go. (This mostly assumes you're mostly working on your servers over `ssh` from your workstation, desktop, laptop, or whatever).

Save early and often.

Create new wiki pages for different processes or stages. Then link them together and link out to any references out on the 'net.  (You know, all those Google pages you used every time you got stuck at any point).

Some of my best HOWTO documents have been created this way.

If you do it right then you might be able to get the job off your plate the old-fashioned way, by delegating to the junior team member ... or the eager intern. :)